# EnsureCapacity should not have if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

I think `if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;` should be removed, I have added items to the full capacity of the list but never hit breakpoint on line `newCapacity = min;`, Can someone tell the purpose of this line as well?

```
private void EnsureCapacity(int min) {
    if (_items.Length < min) {
        int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
        // Allow the list to grow to maximum possible capacity (~2G elements) before encountering overflow.
        // Note that this check works even when _items.Length overflowed thanks to the (uint) cast
        if ((uint)newCapacity > Array.MaxArrayLength) newCapacity = Array.MaxArrayLength;
        if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;
        Capacity = newCapacity;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,eb66b6616c6fd4ef) is the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, two remarks:

- If you want to suggest changes or bug fixes for the .NET runtime, report them in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime)
- You are looking at the old .NET Framework sources. Since .NET 6 [`EnsureCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.ensurecapacity) is public, [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,eb66b6616c6fd4ef) is a more up-to-date version of it.

> Can you give me an example where this condition `if (newCapacity < min)` will return true?

In .NET 6 and above you can easily come up with such an example: just call `EnsureCapacity(100)` on a newly created list.

As for the old .NET Framework code base with the private `EnsureCapacity`: `InsertRange` [calls](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,715) `EnsureCapacity(_size + count)` when the collection to insert is an `ICollection<T>`. So to satisfy your condition you just need to call `new List<int>().AddRange(new int[100])`, for example.

Comment: Got it, so in simple words if the User sets the Capacity explicitly. and the value provided is more than double the current size.

Comment: `EnsureCapacity` is not executed if user sets `Capacity` explicitly; it's the other way around. So if `Capacity` is set, exactly the specified length is allocated, whereas `EnsureCapacity` may perform a doubling if the specified minimum capacity is just a bit larger than the current capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why should it be removed? Seems like this method set's this.Capacity to some number, which must not be less than min. And that is what it does. If newCapacity is less than the minimum specified, it's fixed.

Comment: Can you give me an example where this condition `if (newCapacity < min)` will return true?

Comment: min = 1000, _items.Length = 10, that means will be newCapacity = 20 and hat means newCapacity < 1000, therefore newCapacity will be set to min